# <a > tag dynamically text generation issue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a code which I want to dynamically generate the text by using a foreach class type property value

but when ever I run it, generates a compile time error

Refer the code segment below.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <% 
                            List<CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO> y = new List<CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO>();

                            CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO x = new CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO();
                            x.SessionTimeSlot = "Day 01";
                           y.Add(x);

                           x = new CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO();
                           x.SessionTimeSlot = "Day 02";
                           y.Add(x);

                           x = new CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO();
                           x.SessionTimeSlot = "Day 03";
                           y.Add(x);


                           foreach (CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO s in y)
                           {
                                %>
                                <li class="active"><a href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="sample_Click"><%= s.SessionTimeSlot %></a></li>
                                <%
                           }                            
                            %>

                       <%-- <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                         <li class="active"><a href="#">sfsfs</a></li>--%>
                    </ul>
```

**The compile time error is 
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'item' does not exist in the current context**

**Hope for a correction of this code**

[image]

Comment: can you show the error code.... screenshot of the compilation error

Comment: @Uthistran I will modify my original Question with screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `<%= s.SessionTimeSlot %>` is your problem.
You should use a `Repeater` for this purpose.

Try something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="SessionVORepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="active"><a href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="sample_Click"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SessionTimeSlot") %></a></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in code behind (Page_Load for example):

```
                        List<CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO> y = new List<CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO>();

                        CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO x = new CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO();
                        x.SessionTimeSlot = "Day 01";
                       y.Add(x);

                       x = new CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO();
                       x.SessionTimeSlot = "Day 02";
                       y.Add(x);

                       x = new CodeCamper.EntityLayer.Transaction.SessionVO();
                       x.SessionTimeSlot = "Day 03";
                       y.Add(x);

                       SessionVORepeater.DataSource = y;
                       SessionVORepeater.DataBind();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I changed `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.SessionTimeSlot, "SessionTimeSlot") %>` to `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SessionTimeSlot") %>`, sorry for that :)

Comment: asp:Repeater did not generate any output (blank area) and <%: s.SessionTimeSlot %> still produce compile time error

Comment: Are you sure that `y` is not empty when bound to the repeater?
Does the output window contain any parsing errors or something?

Comment: yes , "y" is not empty , i made break point and checked the generic list count , it is 3

Comment: Rookie mistake, I forgot to add `SessionVORepeater.DataBind();`, have you done that? That's why the repeater is empty.